# Resit examinations

Tags: exams

I am studying mechanical engineering and I missed my exam due to mitigating circumstances.

Therefore the uni allowed me to take the exam again in August but it is classed as a first attempt and not a retake.

The exam I retook today was difficult and I’m not sure if I passed it.

I go to the university of Liverpool in the uk.

If I have failed this module what do you think is most likely to happen ?

Comment: Did you ask your Course Leader and/or your Personal Tutor this question? What did they say?

Comment: We can't answer this question, because we don't know your personal circumstances, and we don't know Liverpool's policies for failed modules.

Comment: Why don't you just wait for the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The school will follow its policies. If you would have been offered a resit if you had taken the exam at the regular time, you will be offered a resit. Exactly when this resit will occur depends on the university and school. You may be able to take it during the next first sit exam period or you may have to wait for the next resit period. More problematic than when you would sit the exam, is if the module is a prerequisite for another module, you may have to delay your studies by a year.

Depending on your schools policies and the details of the mitigating circumstances, I almost always recommended that my students take the exam during the first sit period and then deal with the outcomes. This is because many schools allow students with mitigating circumstances to essentially have two first sits. If you do very poorly, but don't fail, you can talk to the examination board and get the grade thrown out. If you only do slightly poorly, you can ask for the mitigating circumstances to be considered if you degree classification is borderline.